# R plot ratio of success vs continuous variable

Tags: r, plot, aggregate

What is the best way to plot a graph with a continuous variable on the x axis and the ratio of success on the y axis for example with data:

```
x <- c(.1,.3,.4,.5,.6,.3,.4,.6,.7,.8)
y <- c(0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1)
df <- cbind(x,y)
plot(x,y)
```

I want to see values on the y as a ratio instead of 0 and 1. But, need to aggregate x values since the data is continuous and not .1,.2, etc.

For .3 on the x for examle, the point should have a y value of .5 (instead of one on 1, and one on 0).

I want to model success but I don't know what type of model to use, linear or something else. I would like to see the shape of the curve and then find a proper fit.

Thanks!

Comment: It's not clear what you are trying to achieve. Edit the post to be more specific, please.

Answer (score 0):

OK I'm guessing you mean this?

```
> rowMeans(table(x,y))
0.1 0.3 0.4 0.5 0.6 0.7 0.8 
0.5 1.0 1.0 0.5 1.0 0.5 0.5 
> R=rowMeans(table(x,y))

> plot(names(R),R, type='h', ylim=c(0,1))
```

[image]